# Which test to use for this scenario?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

A histogram of white blood cell (WBC) counts in 15 sick patients showed that the distribution was negatively skewed. If we wanted to test for differences between the published WBC count for a healthy population compared to the WBC values in these patients which type of test should be used?

Answer is saying Wilcoxon signed rank test rather than Mann-Whitney and i'm not sure why?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You have a single sample, don't you? Please describe your data in more detail.

Comment: I thought the Mann–Whitney U test is applied to independent samples while the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is applied to matched paired samples. So it depends on your data

Comment: Hi, thanks for replies. It’s a MCQ from my course and I’m assuming they are asking to compare the sick patients with a healthy sample so it’s independent rather than matched pairs? So I can’t initially see why it isn’t Mann Whitney as they sick patients and the healthy sample aren’t related presumably

Answer (score 2):

Just realised the answer. It’s because the second group isn’t actually a group it’s a published average for the population. So it’s the non parametric version of the one sample t test rather than independent t test.

Comment: This the reason it isn't a **two-sample** Wilcoxon test. But you could use a **one-sample** Wilcoxon test (which isn't _exclusively_ for paired data).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what values you may have for WBC, but here is a left-skewed sample of size $n = 15$ with median around $H = 17.$ If the sample in your publication has population median around $\eta = 14,$ then your subjects are from a different population.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = 20*rbeta(15, 10, 2)
boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  8.236  14.891  16.981  16.193  18.584  19.929 

wilcox.test(x, mu=14)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 100, p-value = 0.02155
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 14
```

The difference between 17 and 14 is relatively large. With only
$n= 15$ observations you may not have very good power (ability to
detect a real difference). For example:

```
wilcox.test(x, mu=15)$p.val
[1] 0.1069946
```